# Why do I have to remove "position:relative" in dev tools and add it back before the "top" property works properly?

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs in a nav bar stacked on top of each other inside container elements so they can slide up and down and have only one row visible at a time. Below is the markup and styles, stripped down to the relevant bits. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 as well.

```css
    #searchrap {
        height: 38px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    #searchrap .slider {
        position: absolute;
        height: 76px;
    }
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="miscnav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navlinks">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">...</ul>
         
       <div id="searchrap">
           <div class="slider">
               <div class="links">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">...</ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="search">
                      <form class="form-search" id="siteSearch" action="search" method="get">...</form>
                  </div>
              </div>
       </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

For some reason, when the page loads, the .slider DIV is positioned ~35px too high. I've tried setting "top:0" but it makes no difference. In Chrome dev tools I can uncheck "position:relative" on the #searchrap DIV in the inspector and that causes the .slider DIV to fall into the right position. Then I can check it again and everything is fine--it doesn't go back up. I can fix the alignment issue by setting "top:35px" but then if I uncheck and recheck "position:relative" it makes it 35px too low and I need to reset "top" to 0. I don't like this solution anyway because I don't understand why 0 isn't the top of the viewport.

You can see it in action here: https://www.tntech.edu/dev/ttu15.interior
The search field, which is on the bottom, starts out visible with the nav links above the viewport. It should start out with the nav links visible and the search field below them. What gives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just move your search field outside into it's own div instead of with those links?

Comment: An absolute positioned element is positioned relative to the nearest ancestor with a "relative" position.

Comment: @EricGuan Of course. Only it's not doing that here. The relatively positioned element is at top:0 while the absolutely positioned element inside it is at top:-35px. Removing and resetting the relative positioning fixes the problem but I can't understand why or what to do about it so that removing and resetting it isn't necessary.